# How to declare a covariant type correctly in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

I created a trait with the following signature and methods (details are omitted):

```
trait Cachable[A <: java.io.Serializable] {

   def push(key: String, value: A) = ???

   def pull(key: String): A = ???
}
```

The following code does not compile (`Document` class implements `java.io.Serializable`, and List implements `scala.Serializable` which extends `java.io.Serializable`):

```
class DocsService extends Cachable[List[Document]] {
   ...
}
```

The error message said something like: Cachable[List[Document]] does not conform with type Cachable[A <: java.io.Serializable].

If I understand the issue correctly, the compiler means that `Cachable[scala.Serializable]` is not a subtype of `Cachable[java.io.Serializable]`.

I thought, `<:` statement is similar to java's `? extends` statement, which would fix this type of problem in Java.

How to fix it in Scala?

Comment: this trait cannot (reliably) be covariant, because you are both accepting A and returning A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List` did not extend Serializable before 2.11.0-M3

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7402

Comment: Hmm, any ideas why I was able to serialize scala list, if it didn't implement Serializable?

Comment: `List` is an abstract class, what you serialized was the `case class ::` which is its concrete subclass. Case classes are serializable by default.